# ClassNotFoundException while posting messages to Kafka in Spark Application

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, amazon-emr

The Spark application seems to fail with the below error at the point when trying to post messages to Kafka. Though the error doesn't happen every time but very rarely, is there any issue with the compatibility between the jars that are passed ?

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o26614.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 4 in stage 384.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 4.3 in stage 384.0 (TID 5456, ip-10-164-227-204.ec2.internal, executor 2): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$$anonfun$write$1
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1867)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1750)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2041)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Cluster :** AWS EMR

**Jar :** kafka-clients-0.10.0.1.jar,spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.0.jar,spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11-2.0.0.jar

**spark-submit --version**
version 2.4.4

**./kafka-topics.sh --version**
2.1.0

Please do let me know if any additional information are required.

Comment: `spark-streaming-kafka-0-8` should not be mixed with `spark-sql-kafka-0-10`

Comment: @cricket_007, can you suggest how to see the jars that are compatible. Like is there some sites that I can refer too ? Also just cant understand why the issue doesn't occur all the time if it was a compatibility issue.

Comment: Yes. Spark documentation. There is a reason these packages have separate pages entirely

Comment: @cricket_007 If you dont mind can you point to the sites so that I can have a check on it ?

Comment: Also, `2.0.0` or `2.3.0` version numbers need to actually be `2.4.4` (your Spark version). So, 1) Use `kafka-clients` that matches your Kafka version (2.1.0), then Pick the right Scala version for what you installed (I guess that's 2.11), then Spark-sql-0-10 of version `2.11_2.4.4`, or Scala+Spark

Comment: I trust your abilities to search https://spark.apache.org for "Kafka integration"

Comment: Cool, thanks for leading me the right way. Will check them out, just one question...its just beating my head. Any idea why the issue doesn't occur all the time and it rarely happens as we have been running the same code with the same jars for quite a time now.

Comment: From what I understand, your jars are not being distributed to the tasks correctly. Depending on which server runs the code, the classes are missing

Comment: @Joby did you figure out which jar was missing? I am facing the exact same error. Thanks.